# Is there a way to convert an array of bytes to a number in C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have read 4 bytes as an array from a file from a SD-Card on an Arduino Mega. Now I want to convert this array in one number, so that I can work with the number as integer(The bytes are a length of the next File section). Is there any included function for my problem or must I code my own?

I read the File into the byte array with the file.read() function from SDFat:

```cpp
byte array[4]; //creates the byte array
file.read(array,4); //reads 4 bytes from the file and stores it in the array
```

I hope, you can understand my Problem.

Comment: If the endianess matches you could just do: `uint32_t number = *(uint32_t*)array;`

Comment: @Marius not sure whether that doesnt break the strict aliasing rule. For sure it'd be safer to `std::memcpy`.

Comment: You definitely want to keep [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in mind for this. But first of all: It seems that your file content is binary - is this correct? Are you sure that you don't want to store the number as text in the file? This would make it more user-friendly (as files on an SD-Card are usually also being used by humans to interact with the system (eg. change parameters & settings)) and would allow you to use existing C++ STL functions such as `std::stoi` to perform the conversion.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann The File isn't read by Humans, its an MIDI File and I want to get the size of the Next MIDI-Track and the size is given in an 4 bytes large Number, which I will read and convert to an int to iterate over the Track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the endianess of the stored bytes.
If the endianess matches the one of your target system (I believe the Atmegas are big endian) you can just do

```
int32_t number = *(int32_t*)array;
```

to get a 32 bit integer.

If the endianess is not matching you have to shift the bytes around yourself, for a little endian encoded number:

```
int32_t number = uint32_t(array[3]) << 24 | uint32_t(array[2]) << 16 | uint32_t(array[1]) << 8 | uint32_t(array[0]);
```

Comment: Your first example breaks strict aliasing and possibly alignment rules.

Comment: I had a small problem in my thinking and now it works... Thank you very much

Comment: @C2H6 please keep in mind that the first solution, while appearing to work, may as well break anytime, since violating strict-aliasing rule exhibits *undefined behaviour*. On the other hand, if you referred to the second solution, you are good to go!

Comment: @Fureeish thanks for this information, but I've used the second solution.